# replacing non-alphanumeric characters within a text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to put inside parentheses the non-alphanumeric characters within a text.

For example:

```
"I would like to add * parentheses % around certain text within cells*."
```

I want to put inside parentheses via regex method the non-alphanumeric characters  within above string.

Result:

```
"I would like to add (*) parentheses (%) around certain text within cells(*)."
```

Comment: How should multiple consecutive characters of this kind be handled? Individual bracket `(*)(*)` or one common bracket `(**)`?

Comment: @Codein: a minor detail addressed with a `+` after the pattern.

Comment: @Codein-I want to put inside parentheses Individual bracket `(*)(*)` the non-alphanumeric characters within a text.

Comment: @Selo: then remove the final `+` in the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string s = Regex.Replace(
    @"I would like to add * parentheses % around certain text within cells*.",
    @"([^.\d\w\s])", "($1)");
```

or to be more selective:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(
    @"I would like to add * parentheses % around certain text within cells*.",
    @"([*%])", "($1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

In additio to Marc's `"($1)"` answer, you can also use a MatchEvaluator:

```
Regex.Replace(test, "[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+", m => "(" + m.Value + ")");
```

Which would mainly be useful when you need to do more complicated manipulation of the found patterns.

#### Edit:

replacng single chars and not the '.' :

```
Regex.Replace(test, @"[^a-zA-z0-9\. ]", m => "(" + m.Value + ")");
```

Comment: Good answer, but watch out for that final `.` in the example ;p

Answer (score 0):

you can use [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [Regex.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
string replace = Regex.Replace("a*", "([^a-zA-Z0-9])", "($1)");
```

Comment: Did you test on a string with spaces?

Comment: If you want to allow white spaces, change the pattern to [^a-zA-Z0-9\t ]